# Validate if greater then zero - using valdr-bean-validation

Tags: bean-validation, valdr, valdr-bean-validation

I would like to make sure that `totalAmount` is greater then 0.
I have following code to in my Java bean:

```
@NotNull(message = "Total amount must be entered")
@Digits(integer = 8, fraction = 2, message = "Please enter a valid amount less than 99,999,999.99")
@DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "Please enter a valid amount more than 0")
private BigDecimal totalAmount;
```

Unfortunately `valdr-bean-validator` (tool to use JSR-303 with AngularJS) doesn't support `@DecimalMin` or `@DecimalMax`. Is there any other way to create the rule for values greater then zero?

EDIT: please note that `totalAmount` is BigDecimal

Answer (score 3):

This should do.

`@DecimalMin(value = "0", inclusive = false)`
by default `incluside` is `true`

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't solve it with JSR-303. I finally implemented custom valdr validator.
It is shame that such common case (value equal to zero) is not supported.